# Find the characteristic functional of a stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, self-learning, characteristic-functions

This doubt arose quite unexpectedly when I was asking another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607942/show-that-a-stochastic-process-is-strictly-stationary). I explain:

Let $X = (X_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$ and $Y = (Y_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$ be two independent and strictly stationary stochastic processes with real values and mean zero, i.e. $E[X_t]=E[Y_t]=0,\quad  \forall\, t \in \mathbb Z$.

Now we will define two stochastic process:

1. Consider $U\sim \hbox{Bernoulli(p)}$ a random variable independent of $X$ and $Y$. Define $Z = (Z_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$ as:
   \begin{equation}\label{abc}\tag{I}
   Z=\begin{cases}
      X, & \text{ if $U =1$}\\
               Y, & \text{ if $U =0$}
      \end{cases}
   \end{equation}
   Note that I can writte $Z= X 1_{[U=1]} + Y 1_{[U=0]}$. Moreover, according to same [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607942/show-that-a-stochastic-process-is-strictly-stationary) cited above, $Z$ is strictly stationary.
2. Consider $U=(U_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$ iid sequence of random variables such that $U_t \sim \hbox{Bernoulli(p)}$. Moreover, $U$ is independent of $X$ and $Y$. Define $W = (W_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$ as:
   \begin{equation}\label{abcd}\tag{II}
   W_t=\begin{cases}
      X_t, & \text{ if $U_t =1$}\\
               Y_t, & \text{ if $U_t =0$}
      \end{cases}
   \end{equation}
   In this case, I can writte $W_t= X_t 1_{[U_t=1]} + Y_t 1_{[U_t=0]}$ for all $t$. I believe that $W$ is also strictly stationary.

Before, according to this [topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695456/characteristic-functions-of-infinite-dimensional-random-elements) and its answer, we can treat stochastic processes as random maps with values in the space of functions and compute their **characteristic functional** in the same way that we compute the characteristic function of random variables.

I will calculate the ch. functional of $Z$. Let $q=1-p$ and $\lambda: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb R$ a real function:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\varphi_Z(\lambda) &= E[ e^{i \langle \lambda, Z\rangle }] = E[ e^{i \langle \lambda, Z\rangle } (1_{[U=1]} + 1_{[U=0]})] =  E[ e^{i \langle \lambda, Z\rangle } 1_{[U=1]}] + E[ e^{i \langle \lambda, Z\rangle } 1_{[U=0]}]\\
&=E[ e^{i \langle \lambda, X\rangle } 1_{[U=1]}] + E[ e^{i \langle \lambda, Y\rangle } 1_{[U=0]}]\\
&=E[ e^{i \langle \lambda, X\rangle }]p + E[ e^{i \langle \lambda, Y\rangle }]q\\
&=\varphi_X(\lambda)p + \varphi_Y(\lambda)q\\
\end{aligned}
$$

For me, the second case is more complicated to find a closed formula for the characteristic functional as in the case of $Z$. The most I can do is to compute the characteristic functions of the marginals(as the same way of $Z$):
$$\varphi_{W_t}(s) = \varphi_{X_t}(s)p + \varphi_{Y_t}(s)q, \quad s \in \mathbb R$$
But I don't know if it helps to build the characteristic functional of $W$, also using strict stationarity. Is there a closed form or is it simply not worth thinking about?